# SSJS Accessing a JSON attribute that contains whitespace

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript

I have a Data Extension with a field "Subscriber Key".  I am attempting to access this attributes value using SSJS

```
var subsDE = DataExtension.Init(DEName);
var subsData = subsDE.Rows.Retrieve(); 
var subSubscriberKey  = subsData[0].Subscriber Key;
```

Returns: Jint.JintException:  no viable alternative at input 'Key'

I have tried using:

[Subscriber Key],

["Subscriber Key"]

and even:

```
var sk = "Subscriber Key";
var subSubscriberKey  = subsData[0].sk;
```

None of these options work.  Would anyone be able to please assist?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use 
`var subSubscriberKey  = subsData[0]["Subscriber Key"];`

Comment: Hi Palash, thanks this works!  Would you mind adding as an anwer and I'll mark it as Correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can access fields which contain the whitespace, try to use mentioned code

```
var subsDE = DataExtension.Init(DEName);
var subsData = subsDE.Rows.Retrieve(); 
var subSubscriberKey  = subsData[0]["Subscriber Key"];
```